# Child subcategory or separate category - which one for the best practices

Tags: categories, category-group

I have channel named Products and category group Product Types assigned to it.  As an example it looks like:

> Product Type -> Scent -> Product Collection

And then it comes as Product Collection sometimes has own Product Line (here I have dilemma) or goes directly to a product item (that part I have handled already).

Also Product Types category group is used for building a main menu (using GWcode Categories add-on).

My question is - should I add Product Line for particular Product ABC Collection as a child category or create separate category group Product Lines and there list Product ABC Collection with his Product Line (and how to link it to the "main" Product Collection from Product Type).

Option 1:

> Product Type -> Scent -> Product ABC Collection -> Product ABC Line

Option 2:

> Product Type -> Scent -> Product ABC Collection
>
> Product Lines -> Product ABC Collection -> Product ABC Line

and connect those two category groups together.

I'm not sure which one is the best practice way to go for within EE.

Thanks

Comment: OK, I have figure out how to connect two different category groups using segment tag, but still have no clue which option is more efficient and better for the best practices.

Comment: Did you try both and see what you like? There really aren't "best practices" in all cases with EE (In fact,I'd argue ever). Sometimes you just have to experiment to see which approach works better from a system perspective vs. a developer perspective vs. a content manager perspective vs. a business perspective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some glitches I have decided to go with the Option 1.

Major issue was to retrieve product categories when product was in the cart using `{entry_id}` and GWcode Categories add-on. In that case I was getting all categories from Product Type and Product Lines, which created additional conditional statements to have that issue cleared. With the Option 1 it was straight out of the box.