# Exp-resso store, checkout process and URLs to products in the cart

Tags: expresso-store, categories

Exp:resso Store demo code has that line for a product part (and URL to it) in the checkout process:

```
<h4><a href="{path='store_example/product'}/{url_title}">{title}</a></h4>
```

My products are categorized so it requires to obtain primary category and secondary category for a proper product URL. Is there any way to accomplish that? Maybe GWcode Categories can do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably need to pass the `{entry_id}` variable to another tag in order to grab other fields. I had to do this on a site I'm building in order to grab product images for the cart.

So, if you can feed the entry_id to GWcode Categories, it should work great.

Comment: Side note, just be cautious about how many queries you're adding to the cart template by doing this.

Comment: Passing the `{entry_id}` was the right way to go, but now I'm stuck on "multiple categories" used. For an example I have main category group where is product manufacturer located and then for that product manufacturer I have separate category with product lines I'm ended with both categories listed in the URL :\

Comment: OK, issue was related to a way how product categories were handled. More regarding that "multiple categories" here: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/19305/child-subcategory-or-separate-category-which-one-for-the-best-practices/19717